# How to summarize multiple Intervals in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

In my app I can create projects and for each project I can record work reports. Each report has a start and an end timestamp. A table in the project description shows every report for this project and it also calculates the duration (with DateTime and the diff() function used between start and end timestamp). Now I want to calculate the total work time on the projects but I have no idea how I can do this. I already tried looping through all reports somehow and then use DateTime functions, but I'm getting nowhere... My last desperate attempt was this:

```
public static function calculateDuration($start, $end)
{
    $start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
    $end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);

    $s = new \DateTime($start);
    $e = new \DateTime($end);
    $interval = $e->diff($s);

    return $interval->format('%H:%I');
}

public static function calculateTotal($idProject)
{
  $reports = self::find('id_project = "' . $idProject . '"');
  $totalReports = new \DateTime();
  foreach ($reports as $report) {
      $totalReports->add(new \DateInterval(self::calculateDuration($report->getStart(), $report->getEnd())));
  }
  /*echo '<pre>';
  die(var_dump($totalReports));
  echo '</pre>';*/
  return $totalReports->format('H:I');
}
```

the calculateDuration functions works perfectly, but of course calculateTotal doesn't, because DateInterval does not take a string like "0:30". So that is completely useless...

I hope I provided all the needed information, just let me know if you need something else.

Comment: No point formatting a `DateInterval` as a string and then recreating it as a `DateInterval` object again. Just return the `DateInterval` object from your `calculateDuration` function, or have a separate function that returns the interval and use that internally in `calculateDuration`.

Comment: @cbuckley I also use this function to output the duration of a single report... So I can't change the return value of calculateDuration or I'll have a lot error messages

Comment: That's what I mean by the second option: have a separate function, e.g. `calculateInterval`, that returns the interval object. Then `calcalateDuration` becomes `return calculateInterval()->format('%H:%I');`. Then use `calculateInterval` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity on my comments: You already have `calculateDuration` doing all the work, and it internally deals with a DateInterval object. So why not make use of it? Here, `getInterval` is a protected method that's used by both existing methods and returns the DateInterval object directly. Now `calculateDuration` becomes a simple formatting function, and `calculateTotal` has access to the DateInterval object.

```
protected static function getInterval($start, $end)
{
    $s = new \DateTime('@' . $start);
    $e = new \DateTime('@' . $end);
    return $e->diff($s);
}

public static function calculateDuration($start, $end)
{
    return self::getInterval($start, $end)->format('%H:%I');
}

public static function calculateTotal($idProject)
{
    // ...

    $totalReports = new \DateTime();
    $totalReportsEnd = clone $totalReports;

    foreach ($reports as $report) {
        $totalReportsEnd->add(self::getInterval(
            $report->getStart(),
            $report->getEnd()
        ));
    }

    $totalInterval = $totalReportsEnd->diff($totalReports);
    // do as you wish with the interval
}
```

Comment: works like a charm! Just note, that when you use this, you don't forget to add `$start` and `$end` in calculateDuration's return command :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, updated :-) I've also added a change to how the `DateTime` objects are constructed, which is a little neater than going via `date`.

Comment: Included that aswell in my system. some more redundant code lines eliminated :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a valid DateInterval format instead of returning hours and minutes:

```
// Untested. Might need escaping.
return $interval->format('PT%HH%IM');
```

Comment: from the calculateDuration function? This function is also used to show the duration of one report... So I can't really rewrite this function. But I'll try something with your advice!